# How to fill polygons with colors based on a variable in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've been working with a shapefile that has the x and y coordinates of the vertices of several buildings, and I am using Matplotlib to plot them as polygons. However, I would like to fill these polygons with shades of red/grey/or any other color based on the number of floors each building has. For example, the minimum number of floors is zero, so all buildings with zero floors would be of very light color. On the other hand, the maximum number of floors is 100, so all buildings with a hundred floors would plot very dark, and between 0 and 100 the polygons would plot darker and darker as the number of floors increased.

I found a few things online but nothing that tackles this specifically. I am new at Python so maybe I am just not aware of the right library that can do what I need.

My code for now is this: (It plots the polygons only, no fill)

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

i = 0
sf = shapefile.Reader('shapefile')
sr = sf.shapeRecords()
max = 10


while i < max:
    sr_obj = sr[i]
    sr_points = np.array(sr_obj.shape.points)
    records = sf.record(i)
    numfloors = records[42]
    x = sr_points[:,0]
    y = sr_points[:,1]
    sr_plot = zip(*sr_points)
    plt.plot(*sr_plot)
    i = i + 1

plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with a `PatchCollection`, and set the colors according to the number of floors using a `cmap`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

N = 10
nfloors = np.random.rand(N) # some random data

patches = []

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
colors = cmap(nfloors) # convert nfloors to colors that we can use later

for i in range(N):
    verts = np.random.rand(3,2)+i # random triangles, plus i to offset them
    polygon = Polygon(verts,closed=True)
    patches.append(polygon)

collection = PatchCollection(patches)

ax.add_collection(collection)

collection.set_color(colors)

ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @tom. I think I am getting somewhere here. I just don't see how the code reads the number of floors for each particular building and plot the polygon with the corresponding color...

Answer (score 3):

Matplotlib has the ability to plot arbitrary shapes, [polygons](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/patches_api.html) included.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
axes = plt.gca()
axes.add_patch(Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0.2), (0.3, 0.4), (0.2, 1)],
                       closed=True, facecolor='red'))
```

add as many as you like.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @rodin, but I have a file with more than 1,000 buildings and stating the color of each of them would not be very practical. Do you know if there is a way of having Python automatically fill in the colors according to the number of floors?

Comment: @JosuBatallas just use a dictionary.  floorcols={"1":"red","2":"blue"}   then if nf is your vector of floor numbers  col=floorcols[str(nf)]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Marjin van Cliet's answer, you could use a dictionary to map a vector of floor numbers to colors, obviously you would need to also set the polygon corners from the dataset too in the loop.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nfs=[2,3,1,2,3] # number of floors 
cols={"1":"red","2":"blue","3":"orange"}

plt.figure()
axes = plt.gca()
for nf in nfs:
    axes.add_patch(Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0.2), (0.3, 0.4), (0.2, 1)],
                       closed=True, facecolor=cols[str(nf)]))
```